# Bootstrap Carousel arrow option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been asked to make a carousel more interactive. A customer should be able to scroll through images within the carousel and be able to click on an image to be redirected to the content related to the image.

The following code has been used (in a Pastebin because it is kind of long): http://pastebin.com/xM51WD1J

I believe the developers of this website made use of http://bootstrapdocs.com/v2.3.1/docs/javascript.html#carousel according to the comments inside the code. Does anyone know if there is a property/option I can enable within this javascript code so that arrows will get displayed and those dots in the right top corner like the ones shown in the example of the website? Or is there a possibility that option is already disabled?

I never ever worked with the code used and the documentation does not give a detailed explanation.

**Edit:** Or should I simply add

```
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
```

beneath the items?

Comment: "http://pastebin.com/xM51WD1J" this link is not working.

Comment: @PHPExpert You're sure it's still not working? Since it does work for me, can anyone else please confirm or recommend me another site?

Comment: I think I already found it, it's within my question and CSS display property seemed to be on 'none'.